# How to calculated the integral of the area $C$ of $\mathbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm doing a lon capa problem. It has two parts and I'm stuck on the second part. I first had to calculate the potential of the field. I did this and got it correct. Now I have to find $\textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{r}$ but I don't know how to do this. Can someone give me a few hints?

Problem: Now calculate $\textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{r}$ where $C$ is the path of the parabola $y=x^2−6x+8$ from the point $(0,8)$ to the point $(3,−1)$. You also have $f(x,y)$ which I calculated in part one of them problem.

Comment: For us to solve the problem, we need $F(x,y)$. However, the method is as follows: $dr = dx\cdot (1, y'(x)) = dx\cdot (2x - 6)$. Now integrate the $1$-form $F_{1}(x,y(x)) + (2x-6)\cdot F_{2}(x,y(x)) dx$ from $0$ to $8$.

Comment: F(x,y) =  (5x^2y)+(3xy^2)+(2xy)+(3y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral can often be computed by in parametric form:

\begin{align}
\int_{C}\vec F\cdot d\vec r = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\vec F(x(t),y(t))\cdot\frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}dt
\end{align}

Choose a parameterization for the curve $C$. A possible choice for this problem could be $\vec r(t)=(t,t^2-6t+8)\rightarrow  \vec r'(t)=(1,2t-6)$. The point (0,8) corresponds to $t_i=0$ and the point (3,-1) corresponds to $t_f=3$. So writing everything in terms of $t$ we can compute the line integral. However, from the way you stated the problem, I assume you are interested in computing the line integral of a "conservative" vector field over $C$. ie. the gradient field of the scalar function you posted. In this special case the integral is independent of the path taken between the end points. Observe:

\begin{align}
\int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec r =\int_C \nabla f\cdot d\vec r =\int_C(f_x,f_y)\cdot(dx,dy)=\int_C f_xdx+f_ydy=\int df=f|_a^b
\end{align}

Where $a$ and $b$ are the endpoints you have listed and my $f$ is your $F$.